# Triple tap required for opening files/folders

Tags: touchpad, libinput, tap

On my Xubuntu Core 18.04, I need to triple tap every time I want to open a file or folder in Thunar or other applications' (libreoffice, abiword, notepadqq, etc.) menus.

Double tap does nothing. The problem occurs w/ my Logitech K400 Professional keyboard/touchpad only.

Any fix/workaround suggestions? Should I change some of the following options? Is there an option to enable double tapping?

```
rf@x4580:~$ xinput list-props 10
Device 'Logitech K400 Pro':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 2.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 4.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (280):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (281):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (282):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (283):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (284):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (285): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (286): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (287):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (288):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (289): 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (290): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (291):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (292):   0, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (293):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (294): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (295): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (265): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (266):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (267):    0, 0
    Device Node (268):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (269):    1133, 16488
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (296):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (297):   1

rf@x4580:~$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
# Match on all types of devices but joysticks
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

EDIT: After checking libinput's [man page](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput), I added the line

```
Option "Tapping" "1"
```

to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` immediately after the first `Driver "libinput"` line and logged out/in. This didn't seem to affect anything, as didn't `Option "Tapping" "0"`

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly a libinput [b](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106720)ug. Must [patch](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105974#c5) and [rebuild](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105974#c7) libinput